# definitions in algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, soft-question

I am interested in algebra and I want to read some good books about it. I have a problem with some definitions like free group or algebra. In some books there are different definitions of them and I'm confused. I want to read a reference book which has exact and specific definitions and main theorems in it.

Comment: Dear mhf, I think Dummit and Foote is a good undergraduate level intro/reference. If you want something more advanced, try Lang.

Comment: which books are you having problems with?

Comment: Many concepts in mathematics have different definitions, and seeing that they are logically equivalent, or in what small ways they may fail to be so, is always a rite of passage into whatever context you're studying. Sometimes some definitions are clearly better than other definitions for some or other purpose, but otherwise it just goes to show that a good amount of mathematics is amenable to being understood from multiple points of view. This is good for learning and healthy for math. Sticking to any one book of definitions is too narrow in the wider scheme of things.

Comment: Speaking more practically, if your difficulty here is with your being unable to see how different definitions of the same concept that appear in different places are actually equivalent, then no book of "exact and specific definitions" will make this problem go away: it cannot change the brute fact that concepts can have more than one definition and that they exist out there in the world!

Comment: @anon You should post your comment along with some algebra book references as answer ;-)

Comment: My question is similar to this one, although it applies to mathematics in general, and not just to algebra.  I am struck by the fact that most (?) definitions in mathematics seem to be standard (?), in common usage, and fairly stable.  How is it that mathematicians can agree on such a large set of definitions?  Is Encyclopedia of Mathematics a good source for dfinitions?  What are some other sources?  Granted individual authors may make minor modifications to some definitions to suit their own purpose or taste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I claim there is no true, objective difference between a property and a definition. Part of creating mathematics is deciding what are properties that need to be proven from definitions versus what are instead *defining* properties. Often there are *morally correct* definitions: those that get the greatest traction in the begining, or the greatest mileage in the end, or are the most aesthetically elegant, or are the most suggestive and illuminating as to their purpose and discovery, or mimic our intuition closest, or have other desirable properties. I am a moral relativist, though, believing that which definition of something is best (even "morally correct") can depend on context.

On the one hand, it would be nice if every concept had a single definition, and every other property was derivative - this would make learning much more straightforward. But when there is no universally best definition (just look up "Prufer domain"), it is a disservice to other definitions to pick just one for everybody; furthermore, the ability to convert between definitions is indicative of a fuller understanding of all of the properties related to a given concept. Indeed, being able to think about a concept from multiple points of view is extremely useful in practice - then *all* of the basic properties feel "defining" and are more memorable. Showing that different definitions are equivalent, and then being able to feel that their equivalence is "obvious," is a rite of passage.

Thus I am forced to reject the premise of this question. Being exposed to multiple definitions of things is good for learning math, and having multiple definitions is healthy for the whole enterprise of doing math. In any case, no book of definitions can change the fact that multiple definitions exist out there in the world and are in wide usage by different people and sources.

You might, though, find some definitions hard to understand, or hard to see the motivation of, or hard to see how to use, at least at first. To this end I can recommend *shopping*: shop for the "right" definitions of concepts for *you*, the ones that are the most accessible or intuitive. I do this all the time, which is why I am rarely satisfied with reading just one source (I go shopping for more than just definitions, though). Your preferences may differ from that of others, but a good heuristic is that the more basic or introductory texts will have definitions that are easier to get a foothold with, and you want to learn these first.

For abstract algebra, the text I used in my educational track was Gallian's *Contemporary Abstract Algebra*, covering groups, rings and fields, which was chosen for simplicity. I don't think it covers algebras (the ones over scalars) or free groups. There are a number of good sources online that can be found through googling, though. The shopping you'll have to do on your own, or ask as a separate question (although asking for introductory texts has been done enough times on MSE).

Answer (score 0):

Study Dummit & Foote. It has what you may call exact definitions and all. Sometimes it gives multiple definitions but explains how they are equivalent.

Comment: I might add that Dummit and Foote can be a little intimidating for a first-timer. But it really is the best one out there, I think. If you find it too hard, OP, maybe you should take a course/read a book on linear algebra first (such as Strang's more advanced book *Linear Algebra and its Applications*)?

Answer (score 0):

*Algebra* by T. Hungerford is a very good book and you may find it very useful.